Resources to understand problems posed to Newtonian mechanics by Maxwell equations
Einstein undertook writing his paper on special relativity in response to the CRISIS that emerged in physics when trying to do mechanics for fast-moving bodies in the light (pun intended) of Maxwell's equations that gave rise to some weird problems with Newtonian mechanics.
Could you please recommend a good book or book chapter that covers every detail of this CRISIS and explains it lucidly at an undergraduate level? I know there is an attempt here but it was not rigorous.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the History of Science subsite.

"Special relativity" by AP French
